# How to delete images in Firebase Storage not used in Firebase Realtime database which use their uuid?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have an application that uses the photos in the Firebase Storage according to their uids in the database. How do I automatically delete images that don't have uuid in the database?
Should I write it programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I automatically delete images that don't have uuid in the
> database? Should I write it programmatically?

Yes, you need to do that "programmatically"? One of the best solutions to interact between Firebase services is to use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) which is  "a serverless framework that lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features (or services)".

I understand that you have images in Cloud Storage that don't have (or may not have) a corresponding record in Firestore (or a node in the RTDB).

You don't give any detail on a potential logical flow to implement such a "cleaning" process but you could for example run a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) every X days that scans the Cloud Storage bucket and, for each file, checks if there is a corresponding record in the DB. If not, it deletes the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try "programmatically" XD

Comment: Glad I could help. Do not hesitate to ask a new question if you encounter any problem during the implementation. You can invite me to have a look at your question if you want.

Comment: Hey @commandiron, did you have the opportunity to implement/try the proposed approach?

Comment: hi, thanks for your  attention, I will try this with this steps; read all database, store all uids that used. Red all storage uids. Compare it and delete unused. This is what i intent to do. I will run this manually at various time intervals. I don't want to use Cloud Functions because I don't want an extra complex layer for my project. I will feedback when i am implement.